# Videos In React Going Fullscreen

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I use a video tag in react for some reason it keeps going to the full size of my screen. Can you help me? My Code

```js
import sound from './best.wav'
import vid from './best.mp4'


function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <video controls>
        <source src={vid} type="video/mp4" />
        <source src={sound} type="audio/wav" />
      </video>
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add width  `inline` will help you to control video layouts, moreover, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) documentation will help you understand in-depth

```js
import sound from './best.wav'
import vid from './best.mp4'


function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <video controls style={{width: '200px'}}>
        <source src={vid} type="video/mp4" />
        <source src={sound} type="audio/wav" />
      </video>
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```